# why in my checkout API, url is not valid?

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I use nextjs and mongodb, in my checkout page in api I made a payment stripe session :

```js
import {initMongoose} from "../../lib/mongoose";
import Product from "../../models/Products";
import Order from "../../models/Order";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

// Import Stripe and set the secret key
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

// Export an async function that will be used as the request handler
export default async function handler(req,res) {
  
  // Connect to the database
  await initMongoose();

  // Check if the request method is POST, if not, return an error message
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    res.json('should a post but its not!');
    return;
  }

  // Destructure the request body to get the customer information
  const {email,name,address,city} = req.body;

  // Get the list of product IDs from the request body, remove duplicates, and convert to an array of MongoDB ObjectIds
  const productsIds = req.body.products.split(',');
  const uniqIds = [...new Set(productsIds)];

  // Find the products in the database
  const products = await Product.find({_id:{$in:uniqIds}}).exec();

  // Create the line items array that will be used to create the Stripe session
  let line_items = [];
  for (let productId of uniqIds) {
    // Get the quantity of the current product by counting the number of occurrences in the productsIds array
    const quantity = productsIds.filter(id => id === productId).length;
    // Find the product in the products array
    const product = products.find(p => p._id.toString() === productId);
    // Add a line item for the current product to the line_items array
    line_items.push({
      quantity,
      price_data: {
        currency: 'EUR',
        product_data: {
          name:product.name,
          images: [product.picture],
        
        },
        unit_amount: product.price * 100,
      },
    });
  }

  // Get the JWT token from the cookies
  const token = req.cookies["OursiteJWT"];

  // Decode the JWT token to get the user ID
  const decoded = jwt.decode(token);
  const userId = decoded._id;

  // Create a new order in the database
  const order = await Order.create({
    products:line_items,
    user_id: userId,
    name,
    email,
    address,
    city,
    paid:0,
  });

  // Create a Stripe checkout session
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: line_items,
    mode: 'payment',
    customer_email: email,
    // Set the success and cancel URLs to the origin of the request
    success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
    cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
    metadata: {orderId:order._id.toString()},
  });
  
  // Redirect the user to the Stripe checkout session URL
  res.redirect(303, session.url);
  
}
```

So I checked the url that I passed in succes_url, I made a console.log of req.headers.origin and I found http://localhost:3000
So the url is valid, I don't see where it can come from.
I commented the code for ease of understanding.

Error Messsage : error - StripeInvalidRequestError: Not a valid URL

Comment: First, try hard-coding the URL to `success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/?success=true` etc. and see if it works. I wonder if they want it to be HTTPS.

Comment: I tried it didn't work @ceejayoz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should review your API request logs for [Checkout session create requests in the developer dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs?path=%2Fv1%2Fcheckout%2Fsessions) to see what `success_url` and `cancel_url` values you are actually sending to Stripe. Most likely you will find that this contains an unexpected (invalid) value.

Comment: this is the url of the image that I put in the line_items array of my product, 
It was written in the logs